# th:field gives default value as 0 in input field

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem as mentioned in the title. 
The input field is of type **number**. 
The th:field refers to an **int** attribute in the database. 
I want my placeholder to be visible instead of the default **0** value.

```
<input id="courseCredits"  name="courseCredits" th:field="*{courseCredits}" class="form-control" placeholder="Course Credits" type="number" min="0" required autofocus/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the default of 0 you can't use an `int`.  Instead use an `Integer` with `null` for empty.

Answer (score 1):

Change 'int' to 'Integer' in your entity class.